# Pyspark code improvement idea (to lower the duration)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have severals csv files stored in HDFS, each file is about 500Mo (thus about 200k lines and 20 columns). The data are mainly String type (90%).

I am doing basic operations on those files, like filtering, mapping, regexextract, to generate two "clean file".
I do not ask Spark to infer the schema.

## The filters step:

```py
# Filter with document type
self.data = self.data.filter('type=="1" or type=="3"') 
# Remove message document without ID
self.data = self.data.filter('id_document!="1" and id_document!="7" and id_document is not NULL') 
# Remove message when the Service was unavailable.
self.data = self.data.filter('message!="Service Temporarily Unavailable"')
# Chose message with the following actions
expression = '(.*receiv.*|.*reject.*|.*[^r]envoi$|creation)'
self.data = self.data.filter(self.data['action'].rlike(expression))
# Chose message with a valid date format
self.data = self.data.filter(self.data['date'].rlike('(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*)'))

# Parse message
self.data = self.data.withColumn('message_logiciel', regexp_extract(col('message'), r'.*app:([A-Za-z\s-\déèàç
```

## Then I do a mapping based on a dictionnary, and I finish by steps like this:

```py
self.log = self.log.withColumn('action_result', col('message')) \
    .withColumn('action_result', regexp_replace('action_result',
                                                  '.*(^[Ee]rror.{0,15}422|^[Ee]rror.{0,15}401).*',
                                                  ': error c')) \
    .withColumn('action_result', regexp_replace('action_result',
                                                  '.*(^[Ee]rror.*failed to connect.*|^[Ee]rror.{0,15}502).*',
                                                  ': error ops')) \
    .withColumn('action_result', regexp_replace('action_resul', '.*(.*connector.*off*).*',
                                                  ': connector off'))
```

## Finaly I put the cleaned data to Hive

My issue is the duration of the process; **for each 500Mo files it takes 15 minutes.** Which do not seems good for me. I am guessing that:

- either my code does not follow spark logic (to many regexextract?)
- either what is long is to put in  Hive.

I am wondering why it takes so long; and if you have any clue to lower this duration.

My environnement is the following:
Coding in pyspark with a Jupyter Notebook (connected to the cluster with Livy, the Cluster is a simple 3 node cluster (4x3 Cores, 3x16Gb Ram).
I tried to increase the allocated cores and memory, but the duration is still the same.

I have done the same exercice with Panda in classic python, it works just fine.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: does the spark application run on your machine or in the cluster?

Comment: It is running on the cluster.

Comment: my suggestion to you is benchmark the expressions one by one.